# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) for VPS

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to connect to mysql through the command line:

```
mysql -u root -p
PRESS ENTER (I executed mysql skipping grant tables)
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What's the matter? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you type

```
mysql -u root -p
```

mysql expects a password

try

```
mysql -u root
```

instead, if the root user doesn't have a password set